# Writing 2D array into a file using function in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

```
void IspisMatriceUDatoteku(int red, int stupac, int *matrica)
{
    FILE *f;
    char imeDatoteke[50];

    printf("\nUnesite ime datoteke :");
    scanf("%s", imeDatoteke);
    f = fopen(imeDatoteke, "w");

    if(NULL == f)
        printf("Nevalja!!!\n");
    else
    {
        for(int i=0; i<red; i++)
            {
                for(int j=0; j<stupac; j++)
                {
                    fflush(f);
                    fprintf(f, "%d ", matrica[i*stupac+j]);
                }
                fprintf(f ,"\n");
            }
    }
}


 int main()
 {
    int red, stupac;
    int *a=NULL;
    printf("Unesite dimenzije matrice :");//matrix dimensions rows and columns
    scanf("%d %d", &red, &stupac);
    a = (int*)malloc(red* stupac* sizeof(int));

    IspisMatriceUDatoteku(red, stupac, a);
 }
```

I'm trying to write matrix into a file. If i try to put :

```
9 8 8 
6 1 8 
4 3 8
```

into a file using this code i get :

```
9 8 8 
6 1 8 
4 3
```

So my question is how to get that last element into my file using function like this or there is another way to write matrix inside it. Matrix is randomly generated in another function. Thanks.

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary `fflush` call and add a call to `fclose` before returning from `IspisMatriceUDatoteku`, as LoztInSpace said in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because you don't close the file.  Move your flush() to the end or don't bother & just close the file when you're done.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to see the old C magic is still there after 20 years :)